# Generate a Random Starting Index With jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to set a var default as a random number between two values (1-100 for example).

```
var defaults = { start_at_index: 0,
```

But I don't want it to be zero. I want a random number between 1 and 100.

Thanks

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: jQuery has no random function. The Math.random() is plain javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want it to be just between 1 and 100 (excluding 0), you can use JavaScript:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 99) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// random int between 1 and 100
var random_number = ( ( Math.random() * 99 ) >> 0 ) + 1;
```

p.s. '>>' strips everything after decimal point and is faster than Math.floor (which wouldn't work directly with negative numbers)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with `Math.floor`, no need to do things like `>> 0` which just make the code unreadable to people who aren't steeped in Fortran and similar.

Comment: you mean who don't know basic bit shifts :)

Comment: Re your edit: Even IE6 (the slowest JavaScript engine around) running in an underpowered VM with Windows 2000 makes a function call in under 3 ***microseconds*** (I recently [had reason to check](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2012/02/foreach-and-runtime-cost.html)). There's just no call for this sort of obtuse construction in 99.9999999765932% of cases. :-)